# Error in R lsmeans() function: Error in format.default(nm[j], width = nchar(m[1, j]), just = "left")

Tags: r, lsmeans

I'm trying to find the least square mean of `"post"` by `"group"`. Values of `"group"` are `"TEST"` or `"CONTROL"`.

```
mixed_data <- data.frame(group, pre, post)
mixed_lm <- lm(post ~ group + pre, data=mixed_data)
mixed_lsmean <- lsmeans(mixed_lm, "group")
```

But I received this error and don't understand why:

> Error in format.default(nm[j], width = nchar(m[1, j]), just = "left") :
>     4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3

Any idea?

Comment: I've tried to reinstall the lsmeans package and the code works perfectly. But one day after that it fails again and  the same error occurs. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Maybe it's some other package. Have you done a general update.packages()?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue myself just now on a new laptop. I initially installed R 3.2.0 on it, as I had the binary on a thumb drive. Then, after installing **lsmeans**, I observed the same error when running `example(lsmeans)`. But then I installed R 3.2.1, and everything worked fine. So, my guess is that you have R 3.2.0 or earlier.

Comment: upgrading from 3.2.0 to 3.2.3 fixed the issue for me too.